# I'm researching about geometry non-Euclidean

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I'm researching non-Euclidean geometry.

Now I am looking for a good source for it.

Please suggest me something.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are some wonderful references listed in the Wikipedia entry for [Non-Euclidean Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry).

Here is a link to the website: [*Non-Euclidean Geometry Online*](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/mircea.html): A Guide to Resources.

One book that came to mind, and is listed in the link immediately above, is:

- Greenberg, Martin Jay. [*Euclidean and non-Euclidean geometries: Development and history*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716799480). Fourth Edition.

Answer (score 3):

A very nice fairly self-contained account which puts non-Euclidean geometry in an historical perspective is: Introduction to Non-Euclidean Geometry, by Harold Wolfe, Holt, Rinehart and Winston, 1966. It also includes an account of hyperbolic trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

If only one it has to be the books of Spivak 
"A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry "

Comment: If that's the collection of five heavy volumes I saw the other day, does that really count as one? :)

Comment: yes it is arguable ... but for discovering non-euclidean geometry the second books is what matter (tough depending on your knowledge the first might be a prerequisite..)  .A really nice chapter is about the discovering of the Curvature tensor by Riemann it self (

Comment: ...As a quantity [tensor] that must vanishes if the space is locally isometric to the euclidean space [flat])