# Good book on non-Euclidean geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request

What's a good book on non-Euclidean geometry for undergrads?  Especially ones that consider hyperbolic and spherical trigonometry?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344892/im-researching-about-geometry-non-euclidean).

Answer (score 0):

To the answers that amWhy pointed out, I'll add two more:

1. *Elementary Geometry from an Advance Standpoint*, by Edwin Moise. "Advanced" doesn't mean TOO advanced, although if you've had a course on real analysis and learned about Dedikind cuts, the section about Eudoxus's development of more or less the same ideas will be pretty surprising to you.
2. *Foundations of Projective Geometry*, by Robin Hartshorne. You'll want to have studied abstract algebra (esp. groups and fields) for this one to give full value.

--John